# Downloaded videos from server and save locally through my phonegap app

Tags: cordova, video, mobile, download

how can i get the videos downloaded in users phone through my Phonegap app and videos are on server. Just can any one show me the way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use File Transfer plugin to download any kinds (video, image, pdf, etc,...).
You can find file transfer plugin at

[File Transfer Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

Note that you need to use [File Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) also to access file path or create a new folder or whatever you need.